# Focus event listener not firing on uneditable input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, dom-events

I'm trying to get the focus event listener to fire when a user attempts to enter a P.O. Box into an address field.  I'm not able to edit the input for an easy keypress solution.  What am I missing in my code that I'm not getting the alert?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQQS9/7/

```
<input type="text" size="25" maxlength="75" name="ShipAddress1" id="v65-onepage-shipaddr1" value="" style="" onkeydown="">

<script type="text/javascript">  
    document.addEventListener("focus", function killPObox(id) {
        var idValue = document.getElementById('v65-onepage-shipaddr1').value;   
        if (id == 'v65-onepage-shipaddr1') {
            function runVal() {
               if (idValue.substr(0,4).toUpperCase() === "PO B" || idValue.substr(0,5) === "P.O. ") {
                    alert("USA Light cannot ship to P.O. Boxes. Please enter a street address.");
                    }
                }
                    setInterval(runVal(),1);
            }
        }, true
    );
</script>
```

Comment: `id` is not a string, it's an `Event` object. You can try `event.target.id`

Comment: Why are you adding the event listener to the document instead of the input element?

Comment: Another thing to note is that you're using `setInterval` incorrectly. You should pass it a callback like `setInterval(runVal, 1)` (note the lack of parenthesis). Right now you're passing it the output of `runVal()` which is nothing. The function will run once and then never again.

Comment: @Barmar, I'm not able to edit the input.  It's in Volusion's locked-down cart code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I listed some issues (in addition to a solution at the bottom):

1) As Halcyon mentioned, the `id` argument in your `killPObox(id)` function is assigned to the event, so you could get the values you need by first getting the `target` of the event which will be your `<input>`.

2) As Barmar mentioned, the event listener is being added to the document and not the input element itself.

3) As Halcyon mentioned, the `setInterval()` takes in a function and not the evaluated result of a function.

4) `setInterval()` is not a good solution because this will run your check an extraneous number of times. Especially when the user gets the alert, the user will continuously receive the alert. We can fix this by taking advantage of a more suitable event listener like `input`.

5) The `focus` event is not a good event to listen to. We can fix this using the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event to listen to value changes of your `<input>`.

**The below snippet addresses the above concerns. Run the snippet to see if it functions the way you want it to.**

```js
document.getElementById('v65-onepage-shipaddr1')
  .addEventListener('input', function killPObox(e) {
    var targetValue = e.target.value;
    if (targetValue.substr(0, 4).toUpperCase() === "PO B" || targetValue.substr(0, 5) === "P.O. ") {
      alert("USA Light cannot ship to P.O. Boxes. Please enter a street address.");
    }
  }, true);
```

```html
<input type="text" size="25" maxlength="75" name="ShipAddress1" id="v65-onepage-shipaddr1">
```

Comment: This appears to work!  Weird thing is that it doesn't work in JSfiddle, but works here in the stackoverflow editor.  Any idea why?  (I would upvote the answer, but my rep is too low)

Comment: My fiddle was set to no-wrap in <head> instead of onLoad on the left menu.  Now it works!  Thanks!  Would you be willing to upvote my question so that I can upvote contributors like yourself?

Comment: You don't need to test `e.target.id` since you're only adding the listener to that ID. Just use `this` to get the target.

Comment: This is very true! I will make the modification.